# exporting a web-page to a .text file - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-text

I am working on a ruby on rails application. I need data displayed on a page to be exported in a .text file format like below:

The format of the file is

```
# category name
  ## question
     answer
  ## question
     answer

# another category
  ## question
     answer
...
```

In the index view(whose contents I want to export) I have:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <h4><%= category.name %> Category</h4>
    <ol>
        <% category.questions.each do |question| %>
        <li><%= question.content %></li>

        <ul>
            <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
            <li><%= answer.content %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
    </ol>
<% end %>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new view file eg. categories/index.text.erb
Add your each loop there, remove all the HTML tags, format it the way you need then start your app and go localhost:3000/categories.text
You can save the output with your browser. You can still access the HTML version of the page at /categories